# How come a callback function can still insert into mongoDB even when the client is closed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback

In the following code, the MongoClient is already closed when the callback function of `collection.insert()` is executed. So I'm expecting `collection.insert()` not to work and throw an error.

But it's working, `collection.insert()` works fine even when **MongoClient** is already closed.

How is this possible?

My code :

```
const   MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        connectionUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
        myDatabase = 'library',
        myCollection = 'books';

MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, function(Connectionerror, client) {
    if (Connectionerror) {
        throw Connectionerror;
    }

    console.log("Successfully connected to server");
    var database = client.db(myDatabase),
        collection = database.collection(myCollection);

    var book = {Author:"Mark Twain",Title:"Tom Sawyer"};
    collection.insert(book,function(InsertionError,result){
        if(!InsertionError) {
            console.log("Success : "+result.ops.length+" book(s) inserted!");
        } else console.log("An insertion error was encountered!");
    });


    client.close();
    console.log();
    console.log("Mongo Client is closed");
    console.log();
});
```

Execution :

```
$ node app-test.js
Successfully connected to server

Mongo Client is closed

Success : 1 book(s) inserted!
```

The book has been inserted AFTER the client has been closed. How is this possible ?

Now, on the other hand, if there are two levels of callbacks (a `collection.insert()` under a `collection.findOne()`) then it raises an error, like I would expect (`MongoError : server instance pool was destroyed`):

```
const   MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        connectionUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
        myDatabase = 'library',
        myCollection = 'books';

MongoClient.connect(connectionUrl, function(Connectionerror, client) {
    if (Connectionerror) {
        throw Connectionerror;
    }

    console.log("Successfully connected to server");
    var database = client.db(myDatabase),
        collection = database.collection(myCollection);

    var book = {Author:"Mark Twain",Title:"Tom Sawyer"};


    collection.findOne(book,function(QueryError,bookToFind){
        if(!QueryError) {
            if (bookToFind != null) { 
                console.log("This book already exists !");
            } else {
                collection.insert(book,function(InsertionError,result){
                    if(!InsertionError) {
                        console.log("Success : "+result.ops.length+" books inserted!");
                    } else {
                        console.log("An insertion error was encountered!");
                        console.log(InsertionError.stack);
                    }
                });
            }
        } else console.log("A request errror was encountered !");
    });   

    client.close();
    console.log();
    console.log("Mongo Client is closed");
    console.log();
});
```

Execution :

```
$ node app-test2.js
Successfully connected to server

Mongo Client is closed

An insertion error was encountered!
MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
(...)
```

Comment: Because your insert query is before close call that's why the data is inserted... It doesn't depend upon callback...

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I believed `collection.insert()`'s callback function would be executed AFTER the `close` call. Anyway, I updated my question with an additional example, a `collection.insert()` call under a `collection.findOne()` call. This time I got a `MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed`, which is what I expected. So, why does the first case work, but not the second ?

Comment: Again, because you call the insert first, before the close. In the second case, the client receives findOne, then close, then insert. The call to findOne does not include a call to insert - the call to insert is only made after findOne has completed. These methods are not synchronous (hence the callbacks!), so the insert is added to the event loop task list, but also in this task list - and ahead of the insert - is the call to close.

Comment: Ok thanks to all, I get i now. I misunderstood the use of callback functions (those are my first step with Javascript/Node.js). Now I understand : in the first example insert is called, then client is closed, and then insert's callback is called.
Same in the second example, findOne is called, client is closed, and the findOne's callback function is called, which includes an insert that fails because the client is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The second example works same as the first. 1. Find query gets executed. 2. Till the response comes from database client.close() gets executed. 3. Now when the response is received by the first query, then second query will throw the exception/ error because step2 has closed the connection.

Infact your console.log answers your own question.